# Java recursive method always returns null

Tags: java, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree

I have a Binary search tree and I want to get the subtree with a specific value like this:

```
private Node getNode(Node root,Object c){

        String data = String.valueOf(c);
        if(root !=  null) {
            getNode(root.left,c);
            if(root.data.equals(data)){
                System.out.println("found!!");
                 return root;
              }
            getNode(root.right,c);
          }
        return null;
    }

System.out.println(getNode(root,c));
```

output:

"found!!"

null

but it always returns a null value. I want to know why and how to fix this problem.Thanks!

Comment: Use a debugger to find it out. My first guess is, that `root` is null

Comment: You do nothing with the return values from the recursive calls,

Comment: The root is not null.

Comment: You should do that root data check as the very first thing, not after you get the left node, which could be null

Comment: The parameter named root is null, that's when your method returns null. You reach the end of the tree and return no other value

Comment: @cricket_007: Not necessarily. The `return null` is not in an `else` block. So it could be that root is not null and just no other return is hit before that and it therefor reaches the `return null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not evaluating the results returned by `getNode(root.left, c)` and `getNode(root.right, c)`.

Correct would be:

```
private Node getNode(Node root, Object c) {
    String datac = String.valueOf(c);
    if(root == null) return null;
    if(Objects.equals(datac, root.data)) return root;
    Node tmp;
    return ((tmp = getNode(root.left, c)) != null) ? tmp : getNode(root.right, c);
}
```